# apk cache in gitlab cicd

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, alpine-linux, alpine-package-keeper

I have organized my cicd steps via multiple jobs and to provide files necessary in later jobs or to speed up repeated jobs I cache most of the created files inside the job.

While for most things this works as expected I fail with alpine apk caching.

My .gitlab-ci.yml looks the following and is based on https://gist.github.com/Himura2la/dc054311c96d2737f11dbef6880b61b8:

```yaml
stages:
- prepare
- build

.job_template: &job_config
  variables:
    APK_CACHE_DIR: $CI_PROJECT_DIR/.cache/apk
    APK_PACKAGES:
      bash
  cache:
    key: $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
    paths:
      - $APK_CACHE_DIR
  image: alpine

prepare_alpine_cache:
  <<: *job_config
  stage: prepare
  script:
    - apk update --cache-dir $APK_CACHE_DIR
    - apk add --cache-dir $APK_CACHE_DIR $APK_PACKAGES

do_stuff1:
  <<: *job_config
  stage: build
  script:
    - /bin/bash .gitlab-ci.d/do_stuff1.sh

do_stuff2:
  <<: *job_config
  stage: build
  script:
    - /bin/bash .gitlab-ci.d/do_stuff2.sh
```

which results in following error:

```bash
WARNING: .cache/apk: no matching files. Ensure that the artifact path is relative to the working directory (/builds/my-group/my-project)
```

I checked the working directory and couldn't find the `.cache` dir.

Reading https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Package_Keeper#Local_Cache doesn't help me either since on the Docker Image `setup-apkcache` is not found.

How to cache the packages between jobs? I've done similar with ubuntu images in the past, but don't want to stick with ubuntu for obvious reasons.

Comment: I think there is a missing `/` between `$CI_PROJECT_DIR` and `.cache` when declaring your `APK_CACHE_DIR` variable on line 7.

Comment: Yes you are right. Sadly this was only a typo from creating the minimal. tested already different other solutions: with dot notation and without, with $CI_PROJECT_DIR (like above) and without. All result in the same Issue. It seems that the `cache-dir` flag has no affect.

Comment: Quick question: If the package is installed on prep stage then why it needs to add again in another job?

Comment: That is a very good question to which I don't know the complete answer. From my experience with caching on ubuntu images I thought alpine works in a similar but I fear it doesn't. On the other hand the data is already cached and the installation is general fast.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create cache folder, please add `mkdir -p $APK_CACHE_DIR` to `prepare_alpine_cache` stage.

Comment: yes you are right, this actually solves the cache problem int the job `prepare_alpine_cache` but the following jobs are failing because they don't have access to `/bin/bash`. Do I need to add bash in a `before_script` and alpine is using the cache in this case?

Comment: Yes, you're right. `apk update && apk add bash` should work.

Comment: So the cache is only for the downloaded data, not for the actual installation? Seems fine, but I expected similar behavior as apt.